# Internal fileds (columns) in Room's Entity

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I'd like to mark some Room entity's properties as internal. E.g.

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
class User {
    // ...
    @ColumnInfo(name = "admin_id")
    internal var adminId: String? = null
}
```

However, this produce compile errors like:
`Error:(10, 1) error: Cannot find getter for field.`

The only way how to make this works seems to use `lateinit` modifier, though, it can't be used for nullable neither primitive fields.

I've tried a "hack": a private field with internal getter/setter, but that doesn't work either.

The compiled generated version obviously adds some suffix to the generated methods (`setAdminId$sdk_debug`) that doesn't work with room. The "lateinited" field's setters/getters have this suffix too, but the field stay itself public.

Is there any way how to make columns internal?

Comment: why do you want to make it internal?

Comment: Because it is internal field that should not be exposed to other developers. Of course, I can make some other class and do mapping each time I return or receive an object, but that's a far more complex and far less efficient, that just an internal modifier.

Comment: unfortunately this is what you have to do. Just create another layer that fetches data from Room and translate your original object to another.

Comment: I'd like to do the same (marking entities as internal) and it's unfortunate that it's not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems its getting supported in latest [Room 2.5.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.5.0-alpha01)

---

Old answer: I didn't solve this and I have to define new set of entities and mapper between them.

Answer (score 0):

The internal names get mangled by *Kotlin*, so I made it work by just making sure the correct name is used with `@JvmName`:

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
class User {
    // ...
    @ColumnInfo(name = "admin_id")
    @get:JvmName("adminId")
    internal var adminId: String? = null
}
```

**Note**: This might make it easier to accidentally use this from *Java* then.